# Omnis ODBC 64bit

Tags: odbc

I am trying to access an Omnis database on MacOSX using a c# .NET application on Windows 2008 64 bit.
This is a can of worms! There is no 64 bit driver for Omnis for Windows 2008 - I have tried the 32 bit one but the feedback from this site is that 64bit applications cannot access 32 bit ODBC drivers.

Other than exporting all the data does anyone have any suggestions, including products which may provide a solution here? Thanks Mike

Answer (score 0):

We, at [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com) have a [Multi-tier ODBC to ODBC Bridge](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-odbc-mt/) that might help...

You could configure it like this -

Windows Client --

- 64bit ODBC Application
- 64bit OpenLink Generic ODBC Driver (Multi-tier client)
- 32bit OpenLink Request Broker (Multi-tier server)
- 32bit ODBC Agent (Multi-tier server)
- 32bit Omnis ODBC Driver + 32bit configured DSN

Mac Server --

- Omnis

So, basically, the ODBC to ODBC Bridge is simply being used to bridge from 64bit client components to 32bit server components - all on the same machine...

Whilst this may not be the most graceful solution - in the absence of a dedicated 64bit Omnis ODBC Driver it may be all you have available to you...

Answer (score 0):

You've got to use the 32 bit ODBC manager in windows.  Via a command prompt, go to

```
%system%\syswow64
```

and launch **odbcad32.exe**

After that has come up, you can edit your odbc entries as you expect and the 32 bit Omnis application will be able to see them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this driver in conjunction with the 32-bit ODBC Administrator, the 32bit ODBC Administrator can be found at:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ODBCAD32.exe
```

Right click the link in Start/Administrator Tools/DataSources (ODBC) and change the path to:

```
%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
```

Navigate to 'regedit' with the 'RUN' command, then locate 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Wow6432Node/Omnis ODBC Driver'

Modify the line 'Driver' to

> '%windir%\Windows\SysWOW64\Omnis\omodbc32.dll'

Modify the line 'Setup' to

> '%windir%\Windows\SysWOW64\Omnis\omodbc32.dll'